# How to count all even digits in a number? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

I need to solve a problem where I need to count all even digits in a number.
I took the number 123456 as an example. In it, the sum of even digits is 2 + 4 + 6 = 12. But I get 6 and not 12. What am I doing wrong?

```
n = int(123456)
sum = 0
while n > 0:
    if n % 10 % 2 == 0:
        sum = sum + n % 10
    n = n/10
print(sum)
```

I am just starting to program. please tell me what my mistake is.

Answer (score 1):

Use the integer form of division and your code will work as you intended.  That is, replace this line:

```
n = n/10
```

with this one:

```
n = n//10
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using n/10 which returns a decimal part ex: 123/10 gives 12.3 that's why you're getting an wrong output.

There are two ways to solve this error.

1. using math.floor 
   `n = Math.floor(n/10)`

(or)

2. use // operator which only returns quotient. 
   `n = n/10`